# Nested regex replacement

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I need to create the laravel migrations, so I have converted my SQL script to a laravel migration format using "replacement in files" with regular expressions from Sublime Text.

My problem is that i have to replace in the following string the '@' character by the 'tablename' in about 70 tables:

```php
Schema::table('tablename', function($table) {
        $table->dropForeign('@_columnname_foreign');
});
```

Actually I can do this using the following expression:

```
(Schema::table\('([a-z]+)',[\s]*function\(\$table\)[\s]*{[\s]*\$table->dropForeign\(')@(_[a-z_]+'\);)
```

And in the replace field:

```
$1$2$3
```

but I don't know how to do when the table has more than one fk:

```
Schema::table('tablename1', function($table) {
    $table->dropForeign('@_field1_foreign');
    $table->dropForeign('@_field2_foreign');
    $table->dropForeign('@_field3_foreign');
    $table->dropForeign('@_field4_foreign');
    $table->dropForeign('@_field5_foreign');
    $table->dropForeign('@_field6_foreign');
});
```

I have been using this site to validate my regular expressions [RegExr](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: @revo, I just made sure: there is a difference between SublimeTex2 and SublimeText3 regex implementations. Removing my comments.

Comment: That's weird. Removing mines. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an easy task for a regex in Sublime Text. The only way to do it with a regex is to make sure you capture the function singature with the optional number of `table-dropForeign` lines (matched lazily), and replace `@`s on the next line.

**The regex below requires clicking *Replace All* multiple times until all matches are found**.

```
(Schema::table\('([a-z0-9]+)',\s*function\(\$table\)\s*{(?:\s*\$table->dropForeign\('[a-z0-9]+_\w+'\);)*?\s*\$table->dropForeign\(')@(_\w+'\);)
```

Replacement is `$1$2$3`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bY2mG9/1), where you may replace the `@` in the second block manually with the table name and see how the match goes further.

**Details**:

- `(Schema::table\('([a-z0-9]+)',\s*function\(\$table\)\s*{(?:\s*\$table->dropForeign\('[a-z0-9]+_\w+'\);)*?\s*\$table->dropForeign\(')` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `Schema::table\('` - literal `Schema::table('` substring
  - `([a-z0-9]+)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ alphanumerics (do not check *Match Case* option to also match uppercase ASCII letters)
  - `',\s*`  - a comma and 0+ whitespaces
  - `function\(\$table\)` - a literal text `function($table)`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `{` - a literal `{` (in SublimeText 2, it requires escaping)
  - `(?:\s*\$table->dropForeign\('[a-z0-9]+_\w+'\);)*?` - 0+ sequences, but as few as possible, matching:

    - `\s*\$table->dropForeign\('` - 0+ whitespaces and then a literal text `$table->dropForeign('
    - `[a-z0-9]+_\w+` - 1+ alphanumerics, `_` and 1+ digits, letters or underscores (`\w+`)
    - `'\);` - a literal substring `');`
  - `\s*` - 0+  whitespaces
  - `\$table->dropForeign\('` - a literal text `$table->dropForeign('`
- `@` -  a matched `@` symbol to be replaced
- `(_\w+'\);)` - Group 2 capturing:

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `\w+` - 1 or more letters, digits or underscores
  - `'\);` - a literal substring `');`

[image]

**NOTE**: The issue I thought I found was related to an unescaped `{` that causes a regex failure in Sublime Text 2. In Sublime Text 3, the `{` in the regex does not have to be escaped.

Comment: Well, this is better than copy and paste in about 70 table definitions ! :) thanks!